# How to make a discretized NMinimize more precise

Tags: numerics, physics, precision-and-accuracy, stability

I am using *Mathematica* for physics research and I want to minimize a Hamiltonian equation with respect to two variables (I have also discretized the problem). I have a single constraint. When I plot the result from `NMinimize` for two variables, the end behavior for one of them is not very stable.

Is there a way of making `NMinimize` more precise, so I can get a stable solution?

Comment: The first thing I'd try is to increase `MaxIterations`.

Comment: I cannot upvote this question, because without a concrete example it is hard to help. On the other hand, someone with similar experience might be able to help you, that's why I don't vote to close this. Isn't it possible to create a very short example of a problem the behaves similarly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increase "the precision used in internal computations" with the option `WorkingPrecision`. This should by default also increase the `AccuracyGoal` and the `PrecisionGoal`.
Using an other `Method` could potentially also help.